# Is it a bad thing if a site map contains URLs that result in a 302 Redirect?

Tags: seo, sitemap

We have URLs that are generated by our Site Map generator. The URLs result in 302 redirects. Will this be detrimental to SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 302 is a temporary redirect, if the content really lives elsewhere you should use a 301 "Moved Permanently" redirect, which tells the indexer (or browser) the correct permanent address of the content.

If you use a 302 redirect, the indexer will treat the content as belonging to the URL that is being redirected from, rather than the URL that is being redirected to, thus possibly splitting the page rank between two pages.

You can view the [HTTP Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html%20HTTP%20Status%20Code%20Definitions) for more detail on 301 and 302 status codes.